# How do I create an empty array in YAML?

Tags: arrays, yaml

```
array_with_three_elements:
- 1
- 2
- 3

empty_array:
```

Is there any way to specify that empty_array: is an array with no elements, such as with `[]`? When I load it into a ruby hash I'd like it to know that it's an array.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

Try using `[]`, like:

```
empty_array: []
```

So in Ruby you have:

```
x = YAML::load("empty_array: []")
x # => {"empty_array" => []}
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that you can go into irb and type something like: "require 'yaml'; YAML::dump({ :hi => [] })" to see what the yaml should be for an object.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that JSON is an official subset of YAML 1.2 and almost a subset of earlier versions. Thus `[]` works for an empty sequence, `""` works for an empty string, and `{}` works for an empty mapping.

Comment: @DanielH Note that YAML parsers may not support line breaks inside `[]` or `{}` structures, which is a major incompatibility with JSON (copy-paste from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml#cite_note-10)) Cheers

Comment: Many parsers are still on YAML 1.1; this is probably what Wikipedia is talking about. The entire point of the 1.2 release is to make JSON an official subset.

Comment: how about strictyaml?

Comment: The reason I ended up on this page is that `empty_array:[]` resulted in a parser error. It apparently only happens in certain contexts. `YAML::load("empty_array:[]")` works, `YAML::load("{empty_array:[]}")` fails, and `YAML::load("{empty_array: []}")` also works. Beware of whitespace in yaml.